# How to dynamically update stackers value in vbar_stack in bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

Bokeh version: 0.13

Python version: 3

Hi, I have a use-case in which I use vbar_stack to plot a list of say company counts, stacked over a period of dates. This is a bokeh app in which the x-axis is the dates and y-axis is the counts.

I have been able to generate x-range dynamically by this 
    `p.x_range.factors = [] 
    p.x_range.factors = list(dates)`

But since the company list is also changing dynamically how do I update stackers in runtime.

I think stackers cannot be taken from CDS also, I am kind of stuck over this. I would highly appreciate any help on this.

#### Edits to further elaborate the problem

Sorry If I am not able to express my problem statement properly but here is what I am trying to do.

This is my DataFrame, with column names as c1-c3 and their count

```
{
    "c1": [1, 2, 3],
    "c2": [1, 4, 6],
    "c3": [6, 2, 4],
    "dates": ['21-06-2018', '22-06-2018', '23-06-2018']
}
```

Dates are on x-axis and c1-c3 are stacked. Note that this runs on the server(App). A user can select the date range from a drop-down and so, dates, as well as these c1...cn, are dynamic in nature.

currently these 2 approaches I am using:

1. I update the Column Data source and x_range `p.x_range.factors = [], p.x_range.factors = list(dates)`
   then I again call vbar_stack but this is superimposing on previous graphs
2. I set p.renderes=[] this solves the superimpose problem but it clear all axis title toolbar and legends.
   which I tried explicitly setting but it's not working

We recently started using Bokeh I am not sure I am using the right approach
Can anyone help on this?
Thanks!

[image: Approach 1]
[image: Approach 2]

Comment: Does simply changing the CDS (source) not work?

Comment: No @syntonym Stackers param is not possible to give though CDS. I have still stuck over it

Comment: Do you deploy with python server or only static html?

Comment: @syntonym I deployed it

Comment: @syntonym i have updated the question

Comment: Will you ever need to remove companies from showing?

Answer (score 1):

`vbar_stack` is literally only a shortcut for manually defining multiple `Vbar`s with stacked values. If we manually define the vbars it is easier to later append renderers:

```
rendered_companies = []

def add_company_renderer(company):
    p.vbar(bottom=stack(*rendered_companies), top=stack(*(rendered_companies + [company]))
    rendered_companies.append(company)

for company in original_companies:
    add_company_renderer(company)
```

Then if we add a company we simply have to call the function again.

Your approach with calling vbar_stack again should also work if you remove not all renderers but only the vbar renderers. I've not tested it but the following should work:

vbars = p.vbar_stack(...)
...
def callback():
    for vbar in vbars:
        p.renderers.remove(vbar)
    p.vbar_stack(new_data...)

This will probably result in a redraw and maybe loosing zooming/selected glyphs/items, so I think the first approach is better.

If you also need to remove companies later again you can also save the manually created vbars in e.g. a dict and then remove them from the plot if needed.

```
rendered_companies = []
renderers = {}

def add_company_renderer(company):
    vbar = p.vbar(bottom=stack(*rendered_companies), top=stack(*(rendered_companies + [company]))
    rendered_companies.append(company)
    renderers[company] = vbar

for company in original_companies:
    add_company_renderer(company)

def callback(company):
    renderer = renderers.get(company)
    if renderer:
          p.renderers.remove(renderer)
```

Comment: syntonym  I have been talking to Bryan Van de Ven @bryevdv  on Gitter. He proposed a solution which worked for me with vbar_stack itself. you are correct with vbar it might have been easier.

Comment: Nice! Can you post the approach as an self answer (and then accept that) such that others finding your question also find your answer?

Comment: @Sayed Zainul Abideen please can you update the solution provided by (Bryan Van de Ven) with vbar_stack ?